Changing state in context within useEffect gives maximum depth error
i get maximum depth error when i change context within useEffect even with empty dependency array,the error doesnt happen when i change it with a button , Here is the code
App.js
    function Alpha() {
     const ctx = useContext(contexts);

     function ShareComponnet() {
     return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Shares" component={ShareScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
     );
       }

     return (
      <NavigationContainer>
       <Drawer.Navigator
        backBehavior="history"
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#EDC9AF" },
          headerTintColor: "#A81C07",
          drawerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#EDC9AF" },
          drawerActiveBackgroundColor: "#A81C07",
          drawerActiveTintColor: "white",
        }}
        >
        <Drawer.Screen component={ShareComponnet} name="Share" />
       </Drawer.Navigator>
       </NavigationContainer>
      );
     }

    export default function App() {
     return (
      <ContextHelper>
       <Alpha />
      </ContextHelper>
       );
       }

ShareScreen
    function ShareScreen() {
     const context = useContext(contexts);

     function contextChecker() {
        context.setIngrediants([]);
        console.log(context);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        contextChecker();
     }, []);

    return (
        <View
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: "#EDC9AF",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
            }}
        >
            <Button title="Change" onPress={contextChecker} />
            <Text>HELLO</Text>
        </View>
     );
    }

    export default ShareScreen;

Context.js
    import { createContext, useState } from "react";

    export const contexts = createContext();
    function ContextHelper({ children }) {
     const [ingrediants, setIngrediants] = useState([]);

     const value = {
     ingrediants: ingrediants,
     setIngrediants: setIngrediants,
    };

    return <contexts.Provider value={value}>{children}</contexts.Provider>;
  }

    export default ContextHelper;

and these are the logs i get
    {"ingrediants": [], "setIngrediants": [Function bound dispatchSetState]}
    LOG  {"ingrediants": [], "setIngrediants": [Function bound dispatchSetState]}
    LOG  {"ingrediants": [], "setIngrediants": [Function bound dispatchSetState]}
    LOG  {"ingrediants": [], "setIngrediants": [Function bound dispatchSetState]}
    LOG  {"ingrediants": [], "setIngrediants": [Function bound dispatchSetState]}
    LOG  {"ingrediants": [], "setIngrediants": [Function bound dispatchSetState]}
    ERROR  Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls            setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    in PreventRemoveProvider (at useNavigationBuilder.tsx:718)
    in NavigationContent (at useComponent.tsx:35)
    in Unknown (at createNativeStackNavigator.tsx:71)
    in NativeStackNavigator (at App.js:20)
    in ShareComponnet (at SceneView.tsx:132)

I have no idea which component is causing the error. This error didnt use to happen when i had no Alpha function , but I still need to access and change the context where all routes are placed.Is it caused by the way app function wrapped the alpha function?

Move the definition of ShareComponnet functional component outside the Alpha function, or memoize it with useMemo. When a functional component re-renders, the entire function gets re-run and any variables defined within it (that aren't memoized) are recreated. You pass ShareComponnet in as a prop, so every Alpha re-render it will pass a new one into component={ShareComponnet}, which is likely the issue
